# Page to remain scrolled down after he click "Prew" and "Next" button link

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want the page to remain scrolled down after he click "Prew" and "Next" button in my category single page. And not "jump" to top ( on reload)...

Screenshot, http://awesomescreenshot.com/0042dlfk41

Url to test page, http://planeta.se/bullerWebb/nyheter/nattrea/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // ajax pagination
    jQuery('.navBottom a').live('click', function(){ // if not using wp-page-numbers, change this to correct ID
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                    // #main is the ID of the outer div wrapping your posts
        jQuery('.prodWrapper1').html('');
                    // #entries is the ID of the inner div wrapping your posts
        jQuery('.prodWrapper1').load(link+' #entries')

    });
}); // end ready function
        </script>
HTML
    <div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
                        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link', 'Prew', TRUE); ?></div>
                        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link('%link &raquo; ', 'Next', TRUE); ?></div>
                    </div><!-- #nav-above -->
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit you question, and embed the image instead of linking to an external host. Also, for future reference, please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to provide a minimal example instead of linking to a demo site (if the link breaks, future visitors won't be able to see it).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Didn't see you were using the href already, pass in the event and `preventDefault()` would be your best bet.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // ajax pagination
    jQuery('.navBottom a').on('click', function(event){ // if not using wp-page-numbers, change this to correct ID
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                    // #main is the ID of the outer div wrapping your posts
        jQuery('.prodWrapper1').html('');
                    // #entries is the ID of the inner div wrapping your posts
        jQuery('.prodWrapper1').load(link+' #entries');

    });
}); // end ready function
```

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced where the event gets passed in and prevents default.  It should go on the click event rather than right in the ready event.  It should work now.

Comment: I´m new to this.. can you please show me the right jQuery code? sorry

Comment: I'm not sure what `.navBottom a` is because it wasn't included, but hopefully this will give you a decent idea.  http://jsfiddle.net/LN9xw/